# Create flattened WSDL using svcutil for wcf 4

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe, wcf-4

I need to create a wsdl without the extras xsd files as external files, but have them all inside a single file. I need this because they will be imported by Delphi's WSDL importer, that is quite out-of-date. Can I do this using svcutil.exe? If it's not possible with svcutil, is there any way to do this? I have seen very old samples, based on WCF 3.5, but I don't know if they still apply. 
Tks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a popular topic this week. There are several articles on how to generate flattened wsdl but [this article](http://delriodanny.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-generate-single-file-wsdl-ie.html) should get you started. The code in the article will work for WCF 4. For the actual code to create the behavior this (unrelated) [blog post](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/inlinexsdinwsdlwithwcf) is pretty much all this needed.

Comment: At the blog post, it asks to go download the code sample for this extension from Tomas Restrepo's blog, but there's no link or reference to the code. The guy's blog is huge. To have the code? Tks

Comment: Thanks Pascal for pointing that out. I edited the question to add a new link.

Comment: Tks once again for your time.