# Using PHP SoapClient, Trying to Chande XSD from http://localhost to http://mysite.com

Tags: php, wcf, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to consume a WSDL from WCF using PHPs SoapClient. When using the following code

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://subdomain.xxxxxxx.com:7575/?WSDL');
```

I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load     from 'http://localhost:7575/?wsdl=wsdl0' : failed to load external entity "http://localhost:7575/?wsdl=wsdl0"
```

For the service configuration file for the WSDL the specific port that the WSDL is using, specifies:

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7574" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7575" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

The problem is that the WSDL is redirecting to `http://localhost:7575` for the wsdl=wsdl0 file... then all the XSD locations are also listing `http://localhost:7575....` is there a PHP Soap function that I can use to change that to `http://subdomain.xxxxxxx.com:7575/?wsdl=wsdl0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of the WCF service, it may be easier to configure it to produce "flattened" WSDL. This [SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514014/create-flattened-wsdl-using-svcutil-for-wcf-4) explains how to configure it to a single WSDL document.

If that isn't possible, may be you can have them (or possibly by you, locally) manually construct a single WSDL document and have them host it on their site so your PHP client can consume it as-is.